# Missing Google BackupTransportService in Cyanogenmod 11

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-backup

Google backup seems not to be working on my Nexus 4 with CM11 (snapshot M9).
I've the Google Apps installed (`gapps-jb-20130301-signed.zip`), but when I try to list the transports, here's what I get:

```
$ adb shell bmgr list transports
  * android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```

Is this expected?

Under `Settings` -> `Backup & reset` I find this screen

[image: Backup & reset settings]

Comment: I have never, ever installed cyanogenmod over the last few years without something weird happening, bugs and missing features.

Comment: You installed a gapps package that's intended for Jelly Bean. Of course it won't work (correctly). Anyway, I recommend using [PA-GApps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942) if you ever do a clean install in the future. It works with pretty much any custom ROM, it's up to date, and very customizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know that my issue seems resolved installing the latest gapps package suggested by [Cyanogenmod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps): `gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip`.

I followed these steps:

1. download zip
2. copy to `/sdcard/`
3. reboot in recovery
4. install zip
5. reboot device

During the first boot the device asked me for a backup account, but in the `Settings` I had still `Backing up to debug-only private cache`.

Then I set the new backup transport with

```
$ adb shell bmgr transport com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService
```

Without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is ROM related, the .BackupTransportService should be there.
I've checked the list on a similar setup (LG Optimus G, CM11 20140813 nightly)

```
bmgr list transports
  * com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService
    android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```

Have you tried [newer CM versions](https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=mako&type=nightly)?

[(Also see this thread at XDA from Nov. 2013)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/issues-googles-backup-transport-service-t2540560)